# Full wave bridge rectifier with capacitor resistors zener diode and a LED

Tags: circuit-analysis

How can I analyze this circuit? What formulas can I apply and reach the output voltage?

[image: Circuit to be analyzed]

Values of resistors are in ohms, zener diode is 4,7V. Capacitor is 2200 microFarad and 16V.

---

[image: photograph]

This is the circuit, so the output should have been just 4,7v because of zener's value? I have to find the theratical value for it and see if there is much of a difference. 
R2 is 330 ohm in the actual circuit by the way.

Comment: Nice screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

As Andy points out the output across C1 will be peak voltage in (Vp) - 2* diode drops = 10 - 1.2 = 8.8V. (from figures shown in photo)

If no current is taken from the output connector and the zener is 4V7 we can use ohm's law to calculate the current through the LED.

```
                        Iled = (Vzener - Vled)/R2
```

taking Vled = 2.5V  this gives Iled = (4.7 - 2.5)/300 = 2.2/300 = 0.0073 A = 7.3mA

Without this LED load the current through the zener would be,

```
                         Iz = (Vc - Vz)/R1
```

where Iz is 'no load' zener current, Vc is the voltage across the capacitor and Vz is the zener voltage.

This gives Iz = (8.8 - 4.7)/220  = 4.1/220 = 0.01636 A = 10.6(4) mA

However as 7.3 mA is being taken by the LED this only leaves 3.3 mA through the zener.

If any current is taken from connector U2 in excess of 3mA voltage regulation will fail and the output voltage will fall below 4V7.

If the output connector was short circuited the current would be Vc/R1 = 8.8/220 = 0.04A = 40mA

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are already using a simulator so this should help immensely but a simple rule is that the capacitor will charge up to the peak voltage of the AC waveform minus two forward diode drops.

The ripple voltage is determined by the load resistance and can be found on this page [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/75265/full-wave-bridge-rectifier-with-capacitor-filter-and-ripple-voltage). Here's the picture that is relevant: -

[image]

Comment: @BurakYenihayat: Read the data sheet.