# Bridge rectifier ripple under load

Tags: bridge-rectifier, oscillation

Why when I put even a light load on the bridge rectifier output shows 100Hz ripple?

[image: Poor man's oscilloscope]
[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fb833w.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[SR240 datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/843482/DSK/SR240/+5__W9WVCRIaTTBYA+/datasheet.pdf)

Comment: 16 mV peak? Is that correct? Where do you probe?

Comment: @winny The cheap scope shows that, so... I'm probing right on the output terminal and it only oscillates under load.

Comment: Oh! It's AC coupled. Then it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not "oscillation", that's "ripple". The capacitor discharges between the peaks of the mains, which occur 10ms apart with a 50Hz mains and a full-wave bridge rectifier.

The peak-to-peak ripple will be approximately proportional to the load current for small ripple.

See Andy's answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/75265/full-wave-bridge-rectifier-with-capacitor-filter-and-ripple-voltage)

Comment: But there's 4400uF capacitors on the output, I think that should stand for example a 10mA load without any ripple, right?

Comment: Any load will result in some ripple. For a 10mA load at 50Hz full wave and 4400uF I would expect around 23mVp-p.

Comment: And the scope says 22 mV. That's about as good a confirmation as you get.